# Why is Angular not picking up the second time I emit a value?

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

I'm calling a function which just emits a value and then, after 3 seconds it  emits another.
In my app component I'm listening for those changes to show or hide a loading spinner.
The problem is, when `emit(false)` runs after the timeout, the spinner does not hide.

Here's a copy of my code:

**sensors-detail.component.ts**

(as you can see, there's a debugger, I used it to verify the code inside setTimeout ran correctly (I even tried with a console.log, which worked without problems)

```js
  onValveMode(){
    this.sensorsService.statusUpdate.emit(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      debugger;
      this.sensorsService.statusUpdate.emit(false)
    }, 3000);
  }
```

**sensors-detail.component.html**

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm fw-bold btn-primary me-2" (click)="onValveMode()">Open Valve</button>
```

**sensors.Service.ts**

```js
public statusUpdate = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
isLoading:Boolean = false;
this.sensorService.statusUpdate.subscribe((status) => {
    this.isLoading = status
    }
  )
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoading" id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="lds-roller">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.scss**

```scss
:host {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/************************************************ Loadin Spinner Start  ************************************************/

// https://loading.io/css/
.lds-roller {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.lds-roller div {
    animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
    transform-origin: 40px 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: -0.036s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
    top: 63px;
    left: 63px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -0.072s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
    top: 68px;
    left: 56px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -0.108s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
    top: 71px;
    left: 48px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: -0.144s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
    top: 72px;
    left: 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: -0.18s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
    top: 71px;
    left: 32px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: -0.216s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
    top: 68px;
    left: 24px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: -0.252s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
    top: 63px;
    left: 17px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: -0.288s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
    top: 56px;
    left: 12px;
}

@keyframes lds-roller {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.modal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/************************************************ Loadin Spinner End  ************************************************/
```

**EDIT**: as commented by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11871950/kevin) using an async pipe on the *ngIf statement fixed it for me. Change detection strategy was already set as default.

Comment: I assume your using the default change detection and not onPush? I am also wondering if somehow the observable is completing - could you do an async pipe in your app component instead? so l ike *ngIf="(sensorService.statusUpdate | async) === true"

Comment: Oh man, thanks a bunch, I don't know why I hadn't thought of using the async pipe before! That did it! Also, in case anyone else is readins this in the future and is wondering:  yes, change detection is set to default.